# How will a kernel upgrade effect packages I have installed with Nix pkg manager

Tags: arch-linux

I'm using the Nix package manager on an Arch linux system.

Will my installed Nix packages break when I upgrade the kernel on the arch-linux system?

Follow up questions:

1. If so, is there any way to determine which would break and which wouldn't?
2. If so, how can I still get reproducible environments with Nix?

Note: this question is not directly related to NixOS as arch linux is being used as the base system.

Comment: Usually a kernel up/downgrade would not break a package unless the package itself is one that consists of an out-of-tree kernel module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your other software doesn't break, does it? :)

Linus once said:

> WE DO NOT BREAK USERSPACE!

So yeah, unless it's a kernel bug (they do happen), everything that worked before will keep working. The kernel's userland interfaces are very stable.

Comment: Thank you, but then there must be a point I deeply misunderstand about arch itself. If, for example, I upgrade arch linux and the kernel is upgraded, but I try to boot some old images with systemd from the /esp drive, it seems that almost invariably some (not all) software breaks. Usually I can login non-graphically, but not graphically. Does this mean that in cases like this the kernel modules are the only thing that is breaking?

Comment: Yes. Arch does not usually keep old kernels around anyway, so you must have some kind of custom setup. Regular Arch way is you upgrade the kernel, the old one is gone, from `/boot` and `/lib/modules`, everything.

Comment: Yes, I have a special setup because I need to sign the kernels. So the old ones hang around. I will approve your answer after I go through a kernel upgrade and confirm it.